# Using a Custom Site Content Types with Multiple Lists

Tags: list, custom-content-type

I need advice on how to approach an issue. I have created a custom site content type that I plan to use across 4 different custom lists in my site. Most of the lists will use the same form fields, but I do not need all of the fields in every list.

How can I go about doing this? Would I add all fields that I could possibly need in the site content type? I'm just worried that if I set them as "Optional" they will still show up on the form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try creating a content type with the fields that are commonly used in all the custom lists. 
Create a child content type inheriting from the above created content type and add the additionally needed fields. Now you can make use of such child content types in the needed lists.